Condition for 7 points on a cubic stelloid
According to mathcurve.com,

Given $n$ fixed points $A_k$ on the plane, the stelloids with pole the $A_k$'s are the loci of the points $M$ of the plane such that the mean of the angles formed by the lines $(MA_k)$ and a fixed direction, is constant. The curves do not depend on the chosen fixed direction.

The case $n = 2$ gives the rectangular hyperbola.
The equation of a rectangular hyperbola is of the form $a(x^2 - y^2)+bxy+dx+ey+f=0$.
So 5 points determine a rectangular hyperbola if and only if
$$\begin{vmatrix}x_1^2 - y_1^2 & x_1y_1 & x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2^2 - y_2^2 & x_2y_2 & x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3^2 - y_3^2 & x_3y_3 & x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\ x_4^2 - y_4^2 & x_4y_4 & x_4 & y_4 & 1 \\ x_5^2 - y_5^2 & x_5y_5 & x_5 & y_5 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 0$$
Let $A = x_1+iy_1$, $B = x_2+iy_2$, $C = x_3+iy_3$, $D = x_4+iy_4$, $E = x_5+iy_5$.
Then the above equation is equivalent to
$\operatorname{det}\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}A^2 & \bar{A}^2 & A & \bar{A} & 1 \\ B^2 & \bar{B}^2 & B & \bar{B} & 1 \\ C^2 & \bar{C}^2 & C & \bar{C} & 1 \\ D^2 & \bar{D}^2 & D & \bar{D} & 1 \\ E^2 & \bar{E}^2 & E & \bar{E} & 1\end{array}\right|=0$
where $\bar{A}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $A$.
I wonder if there is an analogous condition for 7 points on a cubic stelloid
$\operatorname{det}\left|\begin{array}{lllllll}A^3 & \bar{A}^3 & A^2 & \bar{A}^2 & A & \bar{A} & 1 \\ B^3 & \bar{B}^3 & B^2 & \bar{B}^2 & B & \bar{B} & 1 \\ C^3 & \bar{C}^3 & C^2 & \bar{C}^2 & C & \bar{C} & 1 \\ D^3 & \bar{D}^3 & D^2 & \bar{D}^2 & D & \bar{D} & 1 \\ E^3 & \bar{E}^3 & E^2 & \bar{E}^2 & E & \bar{E} & 1 \\ F^3 & \bar{F}^3 & F^2 & \bar{F}^2 & F & \bar{F} & 1 \\ G^3 & \bar{G}^3 & G^2 & \bar{G}^2 & G & \bar{G} & 1\end{array}\right|=0$?

Some thoughts:
We need to prove the equation of a cubic stelloid is of the form $a(x^3 - 3xy^2)+b(x^2y - y^3)+c(x^2 - y^2)+dxy+ex+fy+g=0$.
From the figure, I guess the following properties of asymptotes of a cubic stelloid are true:

The cubic stelloid has three real asymptotes making 60° angles with one another.
These three asymptotes are concurrent.

How to prove these properties?
Can we deduce from the above properties that the cubic part of the equation of a cubic stelloid is of the form $a(x^3 - 3xy^2)+b(3x^2y - y^3)$?

$b(3x^2y-y^3)$ maybe?

@OscarLanzi Corrected, Thanks!
